# Xamarin iOS Universal Links - can not set checkbox Enable Associated Domains

Tags: ios, xamarin, branch.io, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

In Xamarin iOS, I am using the Google App Indexing component. I have gone through all the prerequisites but am having this issue with the Entitlements:

When I open the Entitlements.plist in Xamarin, and click on the "Enable Associated Domains" checkbox, it quickly un-checks and says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
[Message displayed when trying to select checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ychba.png)

Some things I have tried:

1) Generating the Provisioning Profile with Associated Domains in XCode, deploying to device, and then using that profile and entitlements.plist in my Xamarain project

2) Creating the Provisioning Profile from the Apple Developer portal with the Associated domains enabled in the app ID

3) Manually editing the entitlements.plist as a text file

4) Re-creating a new project, just importing classes and assets

None of the above work.

Q: HOW DO I MAKE THE CHECKBOX ENABLED and WITH NO ERROR MESSAGE ?

Comment: First question, have you got the latest Xamarin version installed, from the Stable channel? Its version 15.2. To me it seems like a corrupt install is the most likely issue. The second suggestion would be to reinstall just Xamarin (not VS)

Comment: Thanks- I do have the latest version of Xamarin Studio Community for Mac.  I can see the Alpha channel update has an available version 15.3 if I switched, but my stable channel is up to date. I did recently reinstall in the last few weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to re-install Xamarin and it appears Visual Studio for Mac has replaced it. When I opened my project in VS Mac, I was able to set the checkbox in the entitlements. Problem solved.